# $\left|\frac{(\pi+i)^{100}}{(\pi-i)^{100}}\right|$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I tried doing:

$$\left|\frac{(\pi+i)^{100}}{(\pi-i)^{100}}\right| = \left|\frac{\pi+i}{\pi-i}\right|^{100} = \left|\frac{\pi+i}{\pi-i}\frac{\pi+i}{\pi+i}\right|^{100} = \left|\frac{\pi^2+2i\pi-1}{\pi^2+1}\right|^{100} = \cdots$$

but I saw that it'd not solve. Any ideas in how to reduce it to a calculable thing that can be raised to some other exponent then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint : $|z| = |\overline z|$ for any complex number $z$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\pi+i=re^{i\theta}$, then $\pi-i=re^{-i\theta}$, so

$$\left|\frac{(\pi+i)^{100}}{(\pi-i)^{100}}\right|=\left|\frac{r^{100}e^{100i\theta}}{r^{100}e^{-100i\theta}}\right|=\ldots\;?$$

**Added:** And the answer by **N.H.** is the generalization of this obserservation.