# Simplifying $ \left|\frac{(\pi+i)^{100}}{(\pi-i)^{100}}\right|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Can you help to simplify/solve this problem?
$$
\left|\frac{(\pi+i)^{100}}{(\pi-i)^{100}}\right|=?
$$

I didn't understand the hint ($|z|=|\overline{z}|$) given in [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1910362/995162).

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of complex conjugates? That is what is referred to in the hint.

Comment: Do you know what is $\overline{\pi + i}$ ?

Comment: The [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1910362/) says $|z|=|\overline{z}|$, which implies that $\left|\frac{z}{\overline{z}}\right|=1$ So you can set $z=w^{100}$ with $w=\pi +i$ and notice that $\overline{w}^{100}=\overline{w^{100}}$.

Comment: $$
\left| {\frac{{(\pi  + i)^{100} }}{{(\pi  - i)^{100} }}} \right| = \left( {\frac{{\left| {\pi  + i} \right|}}{{\left| {\pi  - i} \right|}}} \right)^{100}  =  \cdots 
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert\frac{(a+ib)^n}{(a-ib)^n}\right\rvert &=\frac{|a+ib|^n}{|a-ib|^n}\\
&=\frac{|a+ib|^n}{\left\lvert\overline{a+ib}\right\rvert^n}\\
&=\frac{|a+ib|^n}{|a+ib|^n}\\
&=1.
\end{align}$$